# Recommendations for Motif Based Classification of Time Series with Python

Tags: python, classification, time-series

I was wondering if I could get recommendations for Motif-based classification packages for time series data in Python? Currently I  modified a an old python sax package to work with Python 3.5 and feed into scikit learn's tfidf vectorizor to make a 'bag of patterns'. Which seems to work but I don't have results yet. There is also this package in R https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TSMining/TSMining.pdf. I appreciate any thoughts or insight. Thanks!